# hive using § as delimiter

Tags: hive, bigdata, cloudera

Is possibile to use § as delimiter when creating external table?

I tried that, but I got weird results, in particular each field of the table just created has a weird character at the end.
It looks like § gets trouble!

Have you got experience in that?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you write the DDL statement?

Try something like this:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableA(field1 INT, ...)
COMMENT 'This is the staging page view table'
**ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\021'**
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '[hdfs_location]';